# Privileges for invoking procedure of other schema in a procedure in Oracle 10gR2

Tags: oracle10g, privileges

Is there a privilege in Oracle 10gR2, which can be granted to users via role to execute any procedure/ function of all packages of one specific schema in their own procedures and functions? For example schemas "user1", "user2", "user3" should be granted a role, which enables calling a procedure of schema "produser" under a procedure that has been created for that schema.

There is a "GRANT EXECUTE ON ANY PROCEDURE" system level privilege, but this is too powerful. If a privilege is granted explicitly to the user for one package (i.e. "GRANT EXECUTE ON produser.package_1 TO user1"), it works, but it's not dynamic and would like to have a role based privilege.

I hope someone can help me. If something or everything is unclear, please let me know.

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to do that with built-in roles or privileges, no. You'd need to create your own role and grant that to your users:

```
create role prod_access;
grant prod_access to user1;
grant prod_access to user2;
...
```

Then grant privileges to that role for all your existing packages, or at least those you wan to be exposed:

```
grant execute on produser.package_1 to prod_access;
```

Whenever you add a new package part of the deployment would be to grant execute on that to the role. And if/when you add a new user, grant them your role as part if their creation.

Comment: Did try this, but for some reason it doesn't give the schema a privilege to execute those methods inside it's own method. Calling other schema's method invidiually worked nicely though.

Comment: @user3861781 - if I understand what you mean, that's a definer's vs. invoker's right issue, and is because privileges from roles are not available in a stored procedure by default. [Read more in the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6521884/266304).

Comment: You are correct. Found an Oracle guide for it: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG947 . Thank you for the answer. It's a pity there isn't a neat way of granting those privileges.